# How do i convert a csv file to a json file for python when csv file is json structured?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, csv

**Hello Guys**,

a colleague of mine collected some twitter data (name, follower, etc.).
He uses MongoDB and sent me an csv-export. The typical "pandas.read_csv().." does not work.

The structure of the *csv-file* is as follows:

*{**"_id**":{"$oid":"5cf683d18eb9ad12c84f6417"},"ID":"14400049","name":"Laura*

**This is my Code:**

```py
import csv
import json


csvFilePath = 'xxx'
jsonFilePath = 'yyy'
# read the csv and add the data to a dictionary..

data = {}
with open(csvFilePath, encoding="utf8") as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for rows in csvReader:
        id = rows["_id"]

        data[id] = rows


# create new json file and write data on it
with open(jsonFilePath, 'w') as jsonFile:
    # make it more readeble and prette
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

I get an key error which means that the loop doesnt get rows["_id"]

Anybody there who can help me? Alternative solutions are also welcome. My goal is to load the data into a jupyter notebook.

Thank you guys very much in advance.

Comment: A sample of your CSV with more than half of one dictionary would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like the JSON is stored as a string in csv row.  you need parse JSON. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: @Chris , its the same structure in every line : **{"_id":{"$oid":"5cf683d18eb9ad12c84f6417"},"ID":"14400049","name":"Laura ** and so one...

Comment: I can't see this error. Can you add full error traceback?

Comment: You're asking "how to convert csv to JSON". Every row of `csv.DictReader` behaves as a `dict` which is `python` representation of JSON. So please, add an exact example of input row (because your example just isn't a JSON entry of any kind) and desired output as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
csvFilePath = 'xxx'
jsonFilePath = 'yyy'

csv = pd.read_csv(csvFilePath)
json = csv.to_json()
with open(jsonFilePath, 'w') as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json)
```

I suppose, pandas package can help you

Comment: OP stated in the question ``The typical "pandas.read_csv().." does not work.``

Comment: @MikeScotty yes, indeed. Furthermore my main goal is to reach the "id" in   id = rows**["_id"]** since this causes the keyerror